# Execute a bash script without typing ./

Tags: linux, bash

I'm a Windows user. I'm used to running files like test.bat by just writing test on the command line.

Now I've got a test.sh script I'd just like to execute by typing "test". But it seems like my only options are to rename it to "test" instead of "test.sh", and then use "./test" to run it. But typing that "./" is very annoying.

Is there some way to avoid typing "./" every time?

Comment: Put `.` in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: `alias test=./test.sh`. Do not follow the advise to add `.` to your PATH if your system is used by multiple users.

Comment: Where's the difference with the alias? If I'm in a directory, containing a malicious script "test.sh" script, and I type "test", the alias will also execute it, right?

Comment: Don't name it `test.sh`, name it `test` (or, rather, don't use the `test` name at all because it overlaps a built-in command). Filename extensions are a Windows thing; we don't use them for commands on UNIX. `/bin/ls` is just named `ls`; it's not `ls.elf`, even though ELF is the file format.

Comment: @treuss, aliases are horrible advice too. They don't work in scripts, they don't work from noninteractive shells, they don't work via direct execve() calls, you can't `find -exec` them, you can't run them under `xargs`, you can't use them from Python's `subprocess.Popen()` family of calls, etc, etc. The _right_ advice is for the user to create a directory named something like `$HOME/bin`, put _that_ in their _personal_ PATH, and have `$HOME/bin/foo` live in there to define the command `foo`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed, will do that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so without aliases, we're back to adding . at the end of the path, right? How exactly would a scenario look like where this is a security risk?

Comment: @AdrAs, not `.` at the end of the PATH, `$HOME/bin`, probably at the _front_ of the PATH. A user controls their own `~/bin`, so it avoids the security problems inherent in `.`; then they're just responsible for installing their scripts in `~/bin`.

Comment: @AdrAs, sure, this is limited to those commands a user is willing to manually install there, but how's that any worse than being limited to those commands a user is willing to manually create an alias for? And it's _better_ than the alias approach for all the reasons I listed above.

Comment: (I was about to link to an essay on filename extensions -- at https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ -- but while it's been the classic/canonical thing linked from the #bash IRC channel on the topic for many, many years now, it's also hosted from the home of its author, a friend of mine in Austin, where weather has caused some widespread power outages; seems his web server's down right now).

Comment: Ok, I'll take the PATH-```$HOME/bin``` solution, that sounds reasonable and I should be able to work with it.

Comment: `.` a the end of the `PATH`? Scenario: Disk space almost full, I go to `/home/naughty_user` and enter `ll`. `ll` is a common ugly alias for `ls -l`, so you just want to see what is in that folder. The script `ll` does something with your user rights and next executes `ls -l | grep -v ll`.  You find a large file called `core`, remove it and forget that you opened a backdoor.

Comment: You can add symbolic links to `$HOME/bin` so your programs can live anywhere (perhaps you are checking them out as a git repo)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How do any of your arguments relate to the question asked here. Aliases exist exactly for the use-case the user stated here, to avoid repeatedly typing something. They don't exist to be used in scripts or any of the other use cases you bring against them.

Comment: @treuss, aliases exist to **define commands**, but commands are useful more than just at _the command line_. If your editor lets you type `!make`, or `!ls`, or `!something_else` to suddenly run that command, that's useful! -- but you can't do it with an alias. Similarly, a general-purpose command can be started with `find . -type f -name foobar -exec yourcommand {} +`, but again, can't do that with an alias; so when you use an alias you're making a second-class command that can't do things _every other command on your system_ is capable of just fine.

Comment: @treuss, and frankly, I **entirely disagree** with the claim that aliases are "built for" this use case. `alias something=/path/to/something` is a _bad_ idea, but at least it works reliably; `alias something=./something` only works when you're already in the `/path/to` directory, so 99% of the time it's utterly useless.

Comment: @treuss, ...one thing to keep in mind: the POSIX shell definition has a lot of cruft in it that's left over from the 70s and 80s. That's unavoidable when you're defining a specification that's going to be backwards compatible over the course of that many years, but it also means that just because a feature is there doesn't mean it was part of a well-thought-out design that holds together as a whole; sometimes you've got stuff that just crept in because there was never a good time to break compatibility by taking it back out. Aliases are that kind of feature; they don't add anything useful.

Comment: @treuss, anyhow: You're saying that aliases "don't exist" for all those corner cases, and **that's exactly my point**. When you use an alias instead of a regular command, you're needlessly making the corner cases fail, when you could instead choose a saner alternative and have your shell work consistently across all the commands you habitually use.